# What type of wire should i use to make a jumper on the PCB control board from my dryer?

Tags: pcb, wire, jumper, gauge

[image]Sorry for my ignorance on this topic.

The relay (part G8P-1A4P 12VDC by Omron) on the PCB control board of my clothes dryer went bad. As a result, one of the pins and circle around the pin (sorry dont know the name of that ring) were destroyed.

I want to buy a new relay, take off the old one and solder the new one on. The problem is the ring around the one pin is not there. So I'd like to make a jumper between the bad pin area and the one that it connects to.

My question is, what type of wire (please be specific) is needed for the jumper? The relay has the numbers 30A and 250 VAC on it - is this the current/voltage that runs on the board itself?

Comment: This is unanswerable without further details such as the length of the run. In practical terms, if you use a wire as wide as the PCB trace, given the difference between a round wire and the thin rectangular cross section of a PCB trace it would be more than sufficient.

Comment: Need information about your drier model and how many watts? The relay current will not help as it is over rated. 30A probably means a 2 HP motor which draws 6 amps. But will be more if it is also providing supply to the heater. How many relays are there, and is this the motor or the heater relay? Either way, the solder pad also makes sure the realy is secure on the pcb, so make sure the relay does not wobble when you're done with it.

Comment: Also, is the solder pad for 12V or 250V? 12V line is carrying less than 100mA.

Comment: @indraneel Thanks for responding. How can I know if the solder pad is carrying 12 or 250? The width of the trace is about an 1/8 of an inch, and the length is about a half inch.

Comment: @M.Koz it seems to be carrying 250V. The tiny solder pad above would be for a lower current connection. The copper also looks thick. I don't know how to fix it but a search on the internet  shows this to be a fairly common problem. People seem to have used a thick wire loop to make a connection. Copper wire in enclosures are generally rated at 4A/\$mm^2\$. So 4\$mm^2\$ wire should probably be OK (assuming relay is 50% over rated). It is a bad way to design for a high current relay. Better designed driers and refrigerators have non pcb mounted relays with wire connectors for easy replacement.

Comment: @M.Koz Now that you've added a picture, it's clear the trace isn't a "heavy" one. So you can repair this with 22 gauge wire, in all likelihood. See [this youtube video by Digikey](https://youtu.be/CCOuKLHsSIs), for example. Or else here's [my quick picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcNA3.jpg). Scrape the blue circled area so that it is cleared of debris and flush with the board. The red area is where you want your repair wire to lay down. You can scrape a patch of green coating away, about halfway along it, and just solder from that midpoint back to the relay. But that's not the only way.

Comment: @M.Koz You could also solder a short wire all the way from the relay pin to the exposed solder point at the end of the red area and just entirely avoid scraping the green coating. Or you can find some other convenient point along that trace (that I cannot see) and solder a wire between the relay pin and some other handy location. Keep in mind that you want to minimize exposed contact surface areas. So make the wire lay flat, make it avoid anything that might abrade or pinch it when placing it back in service, etc.

Comment: @jonk Thank you. I'll let you know how it turns out

Answer (score 2):

You need to scrape some protective coating from the trace, then clean with alcohol. You do solder a piece of thick copper wire along that trace so that will touch the relay at the end. Probably you don't even need to buy a new relay, it could be a bad soldering yet from the beginning.

EDIT:

If you have the same issue as shown in the video, then you can simply add more tin to fill the gap. The relay contacts do wear out, this results in arcing, which is high temperature plasma. This temperature is spread over metal contacts to the PCB causing the tin to evaporate and produces the secondary arcing. When you change the relay make sure you won't apply to much heat, it can de-laminate PCB traces.

Comment: I generally agree, with some caveats. I kind of doubt it is the 12 V pair that "burned" out. More likely, the mains side. Relays like this do wear out, but we also don't really know what happened in this case. If it is worth the trouble to repair, then it's worth the small cost to buy a new relay. That one can't really be opened up for inspection. So may as well replace it while working. Also, the issue remains about exactly what happened to cause the sudden failure (didn't sound gradual.) So it may be worth some caution in re-wiring prior to test. That caution takes time to write about.

Comment: Thank you. Marko, do you think copper tape would work?  vi

Comment: @jonk Thanks for the info. I did buy a new relay, it arrived today. I dont expect you to watch, but this video shows the same issue I have. Only in my case, the ring (I dont know the technical term) around the pin has been destroyed i think. At 7 minutes he shows the pcb board and relay https://youtu.be/aZWBjouDPuw

Comment: @M.Koz I think you just mean the "pad." When you replace the relay, there's no problem following Marko's thoughts about replacing the trace with bare copper wire. You are only talking about a trace that is very short on a board like this. So even at 30 A, you can get by with fairly thin wire. 14 gauge would normally not be enough, but this is a very short trace and 14 gauge is way, way thicker than the trace on the board. But the real question is what happened? The video suggests a reasonable cause and effect. But you can't be sure that was the problem. So there is a question-mark.

Comment: If i understand right, Marko you are saying I can just use more tin when I solder the new relay and don't need to do anything else. I wish I could upload a pic of my board. I am new to all this and all videos I watch on soldering show the iron touching the metal ring around the pin. But if I don't have the ring,  will the soldering work? If I just use the iron to heat the pin, then apply the solder does that work just as well?

Comment: @M.Koz Post a photo of your board.

Comment: @M.Koz It's impossible to know if the trace is sufficiently badly damaged, or not, without seeing it. So it cannot be said if just "more solder" would work. If the trace needs additional "repair" then you will have to repair the trace as well as use solder around the pin itself. Or do something else that's equivalent. A picture really is needed. And even then, unless you do a really good job capturing it, it still may not be sufficient.

Comment: Pic has been added, thanks for your help!